# Does ctx.stroke() and ctx.fill() automatically close path in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Is it necessary to include ctx.closePath() if I am going to use ctx.fill() or ctx.stroke() when drawing paths in canvas? 
 Here is an example below:

```
ctx.beginPath()
// point 1
ctx.moveTo(x+0.5,y+0.5)
// point2
ctx.lineTo(x2+0.5, y2+0.5)
// point 3
ctx.lineTo(x3+0.5, y3+0.5)

ctx.closePath() // <--- IS THIS NECESSARY ?
ctx.stroke()
```

Comment: Try it and see ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may get unexpected render results with or without. if the path is already close this method will do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function does what it says, it closes the path, if you want a closed triangle in your example then the closepath() is required, if you want two lines then it's not.

So the answer to your question is: No, `stroke()` and `fill()` does not close your path.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

let x = 10;
let y = 10;

ctx.beginPath()
// point 1
ctx.moveTo(x/2+0.5,y/2+0.5)
// point2
ctx.lineTo(x*2+0.5, y*4+0.5)
// point 3
ctx.lineTo(x*3+0.5, y*2+0.5)

ctx.closePath() // <--- IS THIS NECESSARY ?
ctx.stroke()

// New path

x = 50;
y = 20;

ctx.beginPath()
// point 1
ctx.moveTo(x+0.5,y+0.5)
// point2
ctx.lineTo(x*2+0.5, y*4+0.5)
// point 3
ctx.lineTo(x*3+0.5, y*2+0.5)

ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>
```